# Выборка докладчика, если известно только имя предыдущего

Tags: sql, oracle

В компании решили устроить обмен опытом между сотрудниками. Для этого каждый день один из сотрудников делает доклад. Сотрудники выступают в алфавитном порядке. После того как все сотрудники сделали доклад докладчиком становится первый сотрудник. Создайте запрос который возвращает имя докладчика, если известно имя предыдущего докладчика.

Собственно пусть таблица Emp будет состоять только из поля ename - имя сотрудника. Это не столь важно. Я подумал, что можно склеять её два раза и вывести вместе с rownum.

```
SELECT ename, rownum 
FROM(
  SELECT ename, rownum 
  FROM(SELECT ename FROM Emp ORDER BY ename) 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ename, rownum 
  FROM (SELECT ename FROM Emp ORDER BY ename)
);
```

Дальше мне кажется логичным запросить у пользователя имя, найти первое вхождение этого имени в таблице, взять его rownum, увеличить на 1 и выбрать из таблицы нужное имя. Но как это добавить в этот запрос я уже запутался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы найти следующего спикера можно отсортировать полный список и потом взять из него запись, как это предложил @msi но есть гораздо более экономный вариант который будет использовать индекс по полю `ename` :

```
select 
  nvl(
   (select min(ename) from emp where ename > :input_name),
   (select min(ename) from emp )
  ) another_next_for_last
from dual;
```

С помощью индекса определяется следующий и, в случае если его нет - первый по тому же индексу.

Сравнить варианты можно в этом **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f384c/4)**.

Comment: Спасибо, я даже не мог подумать, что можно так красиво использовать nvl!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tablename
where upper(name) < upper(knownName)
order by upper(name) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: А разве для `A, B` при последнем `A` не вернет пустой результат?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
    (
        SELECT 
          rownum 
          ename 
        FROM
          emp
        WHERE
          rownum = e.rownum+1
        ORDER BY
          ename
    )
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
          rownum, 
          ename 
        FROM
          emp
        ORDER BY
          ename
    ) e
WHERE
  e.ename = 'имя выступающего, лучше конечно еслиб было поле-ID'
```

Comment: ой извиняюсь сонливость напала ))) в главном SELECT надо вывести из подзапроса только ENAME ))) а то ошибка множества строк будет

Comment: Или даже попробовать SELECT (SELECT e1.ename FROM e e1 WHERE e1.rownum = e.rownum+1) FROM... и далее как в ответе )))

Comment: хотя я уже сонный может бред несу во втором случае. Но по-моему опираться на ROWNUM не стоит, т.к. могут быть порядки строк разные в подзапросах... и возможно WHERE урезает их до того как они пронумеруются что скорее всего.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ename,
       coalesce(
           lead(ename) over(order by ename),
           min(ename) over(order by ename)
       )
from Emp
order by ename;

    with t as (select ename,
    coalesce(lead(ename) over(order by ename), min(ename) over(order by ename)) enext 
    from Emp)
    select enext from t where ename='ThinkJet';
```

Comment: Запрос вернёт все записи таблицы, а нужно только имя следующего: " возвращает имя докладчика, если известно имя предыдущего докладчика". Соответственно нужно обозвать поле и добавить внешний запрос.

Comment: Я не знаю предыдущего. Добавьте его в предложение WHERE, и тогда вы узнаете имя следующего..

Comment: Это была цитата из постановки задачи в вопросе: "возвращает имя докладчика, если известно имя предыдущего докладчика". Соответственно, если расписывать условия задачи, то будет "Дано: Имя докладчика. Найти: Имя следующего за ним докладчика".

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы я написал запрос для конкретного имени, назовите его, и я напишу.

Comment: Да, было бы хорошо, так как, возможно, Ваш ответ кому-то подойдёт и было бы лучше иметь уже готовое сформулированное решение без необходимости дорабатывать его по информации из комментариев. Могу сам исправить с Вашего разрешения, если по каким-то причинам исправление с Вашей стороны не возможно ...

Comment: > если по каким-то причинам исправление с Вашей стороны не возможно


Назовите имя.

Comment: Просто назовите имя.

Comment: К сожалению, Ваш дополнительный вариант неправильный т.к. из всей таблицы будет обработана только одна запись с указанным в запросе ename. Имелся в виду вариант с подзапросом когда из всего набора значений которое возвращает первоначальный вариант отбирается только нужное. Посмотреть как это работает можно в SQLFiddle ссылка на который приведена в моём ответе.

Comment: > Имелся в виду вариант с подзапросом

Да. Только сортировка в подзапросе не нужна.

Comment: Да, не нужна. Теперь всё верно. Спасибо за терпение и участие в обсуждении.